# How do you store/ delete items from a temporary cart into a database for MVC ASP.Net?

Tags: .net, database, frameworks

I am currently doing a school assignment that requires me to do an E-Commerce website with APIs. I am working with ASP.Net MVC Framework and ASP.Net web application API.

I've created a product api with items in it and managed to get it into a table form with a Details and Add to cart button. The add to cart button currently pushes the details of an item into an Array. How do I put the items into a database? At the moment, the items will be gone if the user refreshes the page. There's currently no functions to it besides displaying the items and their details in a pop modal.

```
self.addItem = function (Item) {
    self.cartItem.push(Item);
}
Thanks for your time.
```

Comment: lol, congratulations, you wrote two lines of code, but still have a lot to learn. Start reading boyo.

Comment: That's not the only 2 lines, there's way more that I'm not sure on whether or not to post here. I'll add in more I guess.

Comment: You should not, you should only post something after you've tried something, it's not working and you can't find on google why it isn't working and post the full code and problem. Not because you don't know how an mvc application works. For that you have to start reading.

Comment: hmm, I do know that it is similar to adding a new product (CRUD) via the controller but I'm not sure whats the way to go about doing it with the click of a button instead of having users manually enter them into a field the product id and such.

Comment: Start reading about ajax posting. Here's an indian dude explaining it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9Uwrmgu-oE or read any tutorials on how to do that, nobody's gonna answer here, the answer is too vast.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the help. Have a nice day~

Comment: You too, young man.